# How do you read in file content as is in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read in a file which has data points like this:

```
cat out.tx
0229,3051
```

when I do this:

```
dat<-read.table("out.txt", header=F, sep=",")
```

I get 1st value to be 229, 0 is chopped off. Is there a way to read in the values as is so that R does not auto covert the numbers to ingeter etc?

Comment: Read the documentation and then use the `colClasses` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- read.csv('test.csv', colClasses=c("time"="character"))
```

Comment: Curious, why did you name the first element "time"?